# Can I setup linked servers linking SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Basically this is a backwards compatibility question - our report server is SQL Server Enterprise, and all our Production Servers are going from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2008 R2, so will our reports server need to be upgraded to link to the new R2 production servers? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can setup linked servers between the two versions. Whether you should upgrade is entirely up to you.

Comment: I'm not going to lie you should probably upgrade your instance anyway. 2005 is a long way back my friend.

Comment: Just wait until SQL Server 2014R2.

Comment: That answers my question - I was getting errors trying to do this, but that's only because the R2 client box I was hitting wasn't registered. Thanks!